# Node.js telnet chat server

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, telnet

I am trying to make a telnet chat server using node.js

nothing appears when I open multiple terminals and enter text.
i.e. the text is not transmitted to the other terminal

I open serveral terminals and enter

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8888
```

then start typing but nothing appears

```
var events = require('events');
var net = require('net');

var channel = new events.EventEmitter();
channel.clients = {};
channel.subscriptions = {};

channel.on('join', function(id, client) {
    console.log("join");
    this.clients[id] = client;
    this.subscriptions[id] = function(senderId, message) {
        if (id != senderId) {
            this.clients[id].write(message);
        }
    }
    this.on('broadcast', this.subscriptions[id]);
});

var server = net.createServer(function(client) {
    console.log("createServer");
    var id = client.remoteAddress + ':' + client.remotePort;
    client.on('connect', function() {
        console.log("connect");
        channel.emit('join', id, client);
    });
    client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("data");
        data = data.toString();
        channel.emit('broadcast', id, data);
    });
});

server.listen(8888);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified (sort of) your code to show how to send messages to users:

```
var events = require('events');
var net = require('net');

clients = [];

function randomInt (low, high) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low) + low);
}
function generateId(length) {
    var output = "";
    for(var i = 0;i<length;i++) {
        output += randomInt(0,9);
    }
    return output;
}

function sendToAll(data,sender) {
    console.log(clients.length);
    var size = clients.length;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
        if(sender.unique_id != clients[i].unique_id) {
            clients[i].write(data);
        }
    }
}

var server = net.createServer(function(client) {
    console.log("New client: " + client.remoteAddress);
    client.write("Welcome!\r\n");
    client.unique_id = generateId(10);
    clients.push(client);

    client.on('data', function(data) {
        data = data.toString();
        console.log(data);
        sendToAll(data,client);
    });
});

server.listen(8888);
```